# how can i pass the parameter as "integer" in ansible?

Tags: ansible

so i have this piece of `yaml` in my `ansible` project.

```
- name: common | register vim as a type of editor for update-alternatives
  command: update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/editor" "editor" $(which vim) 100
  sudo: yes
```

What I want to do is to register as a kind of `editor`, set the `priority` to 100.

as i can execute this line in terminal, however, i can not write it into `ansible`, and here is the error:

> stderr: update-alternatives: priority must be an integer

Is there anyway for me to transfer the "100" to integer rather than string?

Comment: What a great command, I had not heard of it! Here is more detail of how it manages symlinks. http://askubuntu.com/questions/233190/what-exactly-does-update-alternatives-do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

source from [ansible](http://www.ansibleworks.com/docs/modules.html#command):

> If you want to run a command through the shell (say you are using <, >, |, etc), you actually want the shell module instead. The command module is much more secure as it's not affected by the user's environment.

In this situation, use `shell` module instead.

If you still want the more secure `command`.

Denote **any** shell command to its full path (because no environment is loaded).

Answer (score 1):

it turns out to be i can not pass `$(which vim)` here.

if i change the line to:

`command: update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/editor" "editor" "/usr/bin/vim" 100`

problem solved.